# How to fetch JSON-file from ipfs and display on a webpage (using 'ipfs-core')

Tags: javascript, next.js, ipfs

```
import * as IPFS from 'ipfs-core'

var ipfs = await IPFS.create({ repo: 'ok' + Math.random() })

const metadataMap = new Map()

//content.metadataCid is the ipfs-cid of the metadata.json file stored on ipfs.
var res = await ipfs.cat(content.metadataCid)
//var data = await res.Json()

console.log("** Metadata from Cid **")
console.log(res)

//This just maps the content (content-cid) to its metadata
//sets the metadata for each Content
 metadataMap.set(theCid, res)

 if (metadataMap) {
 console.log('**metadata map**')
 console.log(metadataMap)
 }
```

**The console -**

[image]

I am hosting those metadata files on pinata as well as on my desktop-ipfs.
And you can access it using ipfs cli or gateways.
**eg_link:** ipfs://bafybeibro7fxpk7sk2nfvslumxraol437ug35qz4xx2p7ygjctunb2wi3i/

The link opens in the browser using ipfs-gateway just fine:
[image]

But when I use *ipfs.cat()*, the console just shows **cat {suspended}** (as shown in the image attached)]

I can access the image stored on ipfs using "img" tag without any problem:

[image]

In the image above, the images are from ipfs.
I also wanna show **title** and **description** which is stored in that **json file on ipfs**

**Same issue with ipfs.get() !**

How can I access that metadata.json file and parse them.
Am I missing any step here?

thanks